# Xcode Cannot find a Static Library During Linking even though it is a referenced product

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, build, clang

I have two pre-existing Xcode workspaces.  One, `Parent.xcworkspace` is an iOS application.  The other `SomeChild.xcworkspace` is a C++ static library.  The SomeChild workspace is in a git submodule of the Parent workspace.

I want to take one project from the SomeChild workspace and add it to the `Parent.xcworkspace` so that the code is built and statically linked when dependent projects in the Parent workspace are built.

It almost works, but at link time when building the Parent workspace iOS application the linker emits

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parent-hagqyrdsdfsdfsdfphgbsolz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSomeChild.a'
```

It's true, libSomeChild.a does not exist in the directory ending with `-iphonesimulator/`

libSomeChild *does* exist in

```
/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Parent-hagqyrdsdfsdfsdfphgbsolz/Build/Products/Debug/
```

So, in summary: The lib is being output to a path that is almost the same as in the error, except without the `-iphonesimulator` suffix.

How do I fix this build?

Edit:

This question is very similar but doesn't really have an answer
[Xcode 6.1 static library .a for iOS not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040423/xcode-6-1-static-library-a-for-ios-not-generated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer because I didn't solve the problem.  But the root cause seems to be that the child project is building for x86_64 architectures but the iOS project requires the arm architectures.

In my case it was simpler to add the child code files to the iOS target instead of trying to build the child xcproj and link to the static library.